# Group By, Having and Count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a following sql query:

```
    SELECT * FROM `products_groups` `productGroup` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` `products` ON (`products`.`product_group_id`=`productGroup`.`id`) 
    GROUP BY productGroup.name 
    HAVING (COUNT(products.id) > 0)
```

Could you please tell how to change the query in order to return the total number of rows in all the result?

P.S.

SELECT count(*)... doesn't work in this case

Comment: Unclear, do you mean that you want to return all of the productGroup.name, even the groups where products.id = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT (rowTotal) as total 
  FROM (
      SELECT SUM(1) as rowTotal
      FROM `products_groups` `productGroup` 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` `products` 
      ON (`products`.`product_group_id`=`productGroup`.`id`) 
      GROUP BY productGroup.name HAVING (COUNT(products.id) > 0)
  )as groupRows
```

Answer (score 0):

A COUNT(*) in place of the SELECT * will not work because the count(*) will be applied to each group.  So your results would come back as:

GROUP 1 - 11 rows
GROUP 2 - 2 rows
and so on.

You need the COUNT(*) to apply to the entire query instead of the group as follows:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT 1 FROM `products_groups` `productGroup` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` `products` ON (`products`.`product_group_id`=`productGroup`.`id`) 
    GROUP BY productGroup.name 
    HAVING (COUNT(products.id) > 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

To return the total number of products under your group totals, `Union` a similar query, only exclude the `Group By` and use an `Inner Join` to exclude Product Groups with no Products (as your `Having` clause does):

```
SELECT
  productGroup.name as ProductGroup,count(products.id) as ProductCount
FROM `products_groups` `productGroup` 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `products` `products`
        ON (`products`.`product_group_id`=`productGroup`.`id`) 
GROUP BY productGroup.name 
HAVING (COUNT(products.id) > 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Total' ProductGroup,count(products.id) ProductCount
FROM `products_groups` `productGroup` 
    INNER JOIN `products` `products`
        ON (`products`.`product_group_id`=`productGroup`.`id`)
```